How to Write Documentation for Private Functions
I am writing a paclet and I it has become too big, so I am trying to add documentation pages not only for the public symbols but also for the private ones, so that I can remember what the internal functions do. I am using Documentation tools, but I don't know how to do it for internal functions.

You can write comments in the source code. You can also write usage messages. Consider whether you want to put in the effort to write nicely-formatted pages for symbols your users are not meant to use (and whether you want these pages to be visible to users).

@Szabolcs Like I said, the documentation is meant for me. Naturally, I can write comments, but more frequent than not I find myself reading something and wishing that I had a simple usage example. Besides, the pages are quick to write.

Can you be specific about what the problem is, and what precisely prevents you from writing these pages?

I decided to just leave it as public functions, but have the Guides split, like how  MakeSubscriptBox and the other low level stuff appears in Mathematica guides.
